# How to get client's MAC address by WebRTC request?

Tags: javascript, macos

Firefox and Chrome have implemented **WebRTC** that allow requests to STUN servers be made that will return the local IP address of the client.

The javascript code below outputs the local IP address of the client:

```
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers:[]}), noop = function(){};      
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
        if(!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate)  return;
        var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];
        console.log('my IP: ', myIP);   
        pc.onicecandidate = noop;
    };
```

**Is it possible to obtain the MAC address also?**

Comment: Do you know about arp?

Comment: @oklas It would be more helpful if you would provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot get the MacAdress with Javascript in the Browser. For very good reasons. It would be a big security risk.

The MAC address uniquely identifies the running computer, cellphone...basically every device, an internal IP does not.

You need to use Electron or Node for that, if you want to do it with Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Use **ARP** using any way. You can use OS API or you can spawn command line tool or high level API or library of you favorite programming language.

Comment: I have a REMOTE server that opens WebRTC connection with the client. I wanted to know if there is a way to get the MAC address of the client with SDP.

Comment: @MOP in that case, it is impossible to get MAC address using SDP.

Comment: Can u tell me why exactly? Seeing how I can extract the Private IP but can't get the MAC address while both are parameters from the same Network Interface...

Comment: SDP is a protocol designed according to specification. There is no mention of MAC in its [specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566). Custom implementation can has any deviations but it is not guarantee in common case. Tool on client side (or in its local network in some cases) can figure out its MAC.

Comment: @MOP WebRTC is an application layer protocol built on IP (UDP specifically). IP addresses and ports are sufficient for communication done by WebRTC. Because of that it doesn't care about MAC addresses and makes no sense for WebRTC to gather that information.